# Transposing multiple columns to 1 column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am working with a large dataset with multiple columns. It looks similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Country': ["NL", "NL", "NL", "BE", "BE", "BE"],
     "Year": [2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012],
     "Monkeys": [1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4],
     "Giraffes": [40, 50, 60, 20, 30, 35],
     "Pigs": [10, 15, 20, 30, 35, 40]
     })
```

Which looks like this:

```
  Country  Year  Monkeys  Giraffes  Pigs
0      NL  2010        1        40    10
1      NL  2011        4        50    15
2      NL  2012        5        60    20
3      BE  2010        2        20    30
4      BE  2011        5        30    35
5      BE  2012        4        35    40
```

I want it to look like this:

```
    Animals Country  2010  2011  2012
0   Monkeys      NL     1     4     5
1  Giraffes      NL    40    50    60
2      Pigs      NL    10    15    20
3   Monkeys      BE     2     5     4
4  Giraffes      BE    20    30    35
5      Pigs      BE    30    35    40
```

Using pivot_table and pivot methods I have been unable to get this to work. Is there anyone who can help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `Multiindex` and reshape by  [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) first and then [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['Country','Year'])
        .rename_axis('Animals', axis=1)
        .unstack([0,1])
        .unstack()
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
    Animals Country  2010  2011  2012
0   Monkeys      BE     2     5     4
1   Monkeys      NL     1     4     5
2  Giraffes      BE    20    30    35
3  Giraffes      NL    40    50    60
4      Pigs      BE    30    35    40
5      Pigs      NL    10    15    20
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just wondering, what does [0,1] refer to in the unstack method?

Comment: @brokkoo 0 it is first and second levels

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `melt` and `pivot` should suffice:

```py
(df.melt(id_vars = ['Country', 'Year'], var_name='Animals')
   .pivot(index=['Animals', 'Country'], columns='Year', values = 'value')
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
 
    Animals Country  2010  2011  2012
0  Giraffes      BE    20    30    35
1  Giraffes      NL    40    50    60
2   Monkeys      BE     2     5     4
3   Monkeys      NL     1     4     5
4      Pigs      BE    30    35    40
5      Pigs      NL    10    15    20
```